# Google Protobuf GetString & GetStringReference seems to get the wrong value

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am trying to get the string value from a protobuf message. My *.proto* schema looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package messages;

message Telemetry
{
    optional string key1 = 1;
    optional string key2 = 2;
}
```

The piece of code which is used to manipulate with it:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

    messages::Telemetry telemetry;

    // Initialize values
    telemetry.set_key1("string_1");
    telemetry.set_key2("string_2");

    std::cout << "key1: " <<  telemetry.key1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "key2: " <<  telemetry.key2() << std::endl;

    const google::protobuf::Descriptor *desc       = telemetry.GetDescriptor();

    int fieldCount = desc->field_count();

    for(int i = 0; i < fieldCount ; i++)
    {
        const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor *field = desc->FindFieldByNumber(i + 1);
        fprintf(stderr, "Name of the %i th key: %s, type:  %s \n", i, field->name().c_str(), field->type_name());
    }

    const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor *field = desc->FindFieldByName("key1");
    const google::protobuf::Reflection *refl       = telemetry.GetReflection();
    std::string str;
    str = refl->GetStringReference(telemetry, field, &str);
    std::cout << "Value: " << str << std::endl;
}
```

Somehow, the output looks like:

```
Name of the 0 th key: key1, type:  string    <- OK
Name of the 1 th key: key2, type:  string    <- OK
key1: string_1    <- OK
key2: string_2    <- OK
Value: string_2   <- This line is expected to be 'string_1'
```

Then if I tried `desc->FindFieldByName("key2")`, the program would be crashed with `(Segmentation fault (core dumped))`.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: That is strange indeed. Have you inspected other fields of the `FieldDescriptor` returned by `FindFieldByName("key1")`, like `name()` and `number()`. Also, does the same thing happen with `GetString`?

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce the issue. Copy-pasting the code, I get the expected output.

Comment: @RafaelLerm, thank you for time trying to help me. I have fixed it. The thing that I forgot to mention is that I am trying to cross-compile the program for Raspberry Pi. And I think the Raspberry Root Folder on my host computer were somehow corrupted. The things I have done is re-create the Root Folder on the host, and then I get the expected result.